# How to make sequential list of months?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, google-sheets-dates

I want to fill column names with a sequential list of the last day of each month.  For example, `3/31/2018`, `4/30/2018`, `5/31/2018`, etc.  Is there a formula that can do this?  If cell B1 = `3/31/2018`, I tried this:

```
=DATE(YEAR(B1), MONTH(B1)+1, DAY(B1))
```

But this produces `5/1/2018` since April has only 30 days.

Answer (score 0):

- instead of your formula use **`EOMONTH`**

  ```
  =EOMONTH(B1, 1)
  ```

  [image]
- or you can use a single formula to print the whole array:

  ```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(EOMONTH(B1, ROW(A1:A11)))
  ```

  [image: 0]

Comment: @ElliottB https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution, that looks similar to your original formula, is to use the following:

```
=date(year(B1),month(B1)+2,0)
```